# Struggle with overlay in Beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

I am currently learning how to use Beamer and would like to create a frame that presents 3 techniques for reduction of a class of objects (given with `itemize`). The first technique is the largest among the three and consists of 2 big equations, say *Eq1* and *Eq2*. My desire is to present it with `\only<2-4>` - in other words, in the first step I wish the name of the technique to appear, then in steps `<3-4>` to show the two equations, and at step `5` all of these to disappear and to make place for the other information. What I tried is:

```
\begin{frame}{Techniques}

\begin{itemize}
\only<2-4> {\item Technique 1:
\pause
\begin{equation*} Eq1 \end{equation*}
\pause
\begin{align*} Eq2 \\ Eq2+ \end{align*}
}

\item<5-> Technique 2:
\begin{equation*} Eq 3 \end{equation*}

\item<6-> Technique 3: \pause
\hspace{1em} Algorithm 1 \pause
\hspace{1em} Algorithm 2 \pause
\hspace{1em} Algorithm 3
\end{itemize}

\vfill
\end{frame}
```

however, this doesn't work. It gives directly the name `Technique 1` and *Eq1* (at step `2`), then *Eq2* appears (at step `3`) and at the final step `4` nothing happens. Is there a way to fix this?

PS A similar problem appears with `Technique 3`, where all algorithms appear at once (while I'd like to have them appearing one by one). I suppose though that, if I learn how to fix the above problem, I shall be able to work this one out, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a little careful in mixing up `\pause` and `<n-m>` commands as beamer is not always able to work out what you want. One nice trick is that

```
\pause[5]
```

tells beamer that pause should start counting from the slide `5` on-wards. Another nice trick is that many commands, including `\item`, accept the `<n-m>` modifiers, which allows you to write things like `\item<2-7>` to display the following item only on slides `2` to `7`.

From what you have written I am not entirely sure that I understand what you want, but I think that this is close:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Techniques}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<2-5> Technique 1:
    \only<3-5>{
      \begin{equation*} Eq1 \end{equation*}
    }
    \only<4-5>{
      \begin{align*} Eq2 \\
          \only<5>{Eq2+}
      \end{align*}
    }
    \item<6-> Technique 2:
    \begin{equation*} Eq 3 \end{equation*}

    \item<7-> Technique 3:
    \pause[8]% tell pause to start counting from slide 8
    \hspace{1em} Algorithm 1
    \pause
    \hspace{1em} Algorithm 2
    \pause
    \hspace{1em} Algorithm 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - `\pause[n]` solved the problem indeed. Interestingly, this option isn't mentioned in any tutorial that I looked.

PS I want `Technique 1` with *Eq1* and *Eq2* to disappear after step/slide 4 and to make place for the rest of the techniques (otherwise, they don't fit on the screen). With your fix, utilised to my original code, everything works perfectly ;)